# Problem with mapping user with another entities

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Right now I even dont know how to start implementing this. So I have a user model and it looks like this:

```
@Document
public class User {
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String username;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String email;
@JsonIgnore
@NonNull
private String password;
```

And also I have a model like this:

```
@Document("adventureholidays")
public class AdventureHolidays {

@Id
private String id;
private String title;
private String description;
private String state;
private String typeOfAdventureHolidays;
private String image;
```

But what is the problem? I provided just a `adventureholidays` while I have a seven more.

Where is actually the problem? I want to create a controller that will allow user to save favoruite holiday, and then user will be able to see that saved holiday on profile.

But, I dont know how to map this properly, because if I edit my User entity like this adding `@DBRef` for `AdventureHolidays`

```
@Document
public class User {
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String username;
@Indexed(unique = true)
@NonNull
private String email;
@JsonIgnore
@NonNull
private String password;

@DBRef
private List<AdventureHolidays> savedTripsAdventure;
```

I need to add also for every other entity? like

```
 @DBRef
 private List<Backpacking> savedBackpacking;

 @DBRef
 private List<CruiseHolidays> savedCruiseHolidays;
```

And etc. or there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store in `AdventureHolidays` and other holidays collections the reference to `userId` instead of adding `DBRef` to user entity. Afterwards you can fetch all your user's holidays using an aggreagate query.  As far as I know Mongo doesn't recomand to use `@DBRef`.